# parse xml with lxml.etree.parse(xml_path) [XMLSyntaxError: Start tag expected, '<' not found]

Tags: xml, python-3.x, lxml

I want to parse an xml looking like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Scenario xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Scenario.xsd">
  <TestCase>test_wig_0002</TestCase>
  <ShortDescription>No connection to WIG1 and WIG2 (Hasler).</ShortDescription>
  <Events>
    <Event Num="1">Startup of the EVC without a connection to the 2 WIGs</Event>
    <Event Num="2">Open Cab A</Event>
  </Events>
  <HW-configuration>
    <ELBE5A>true</ELBE5A>
    <WIG1-Hasler>true</WIG1-Hasler>
    <WIG1-16P>false</WIG1-16P>
    <WIG2-Hasler>true</WIG2-Hasler>
    <WIG2-16P>false</WIG2-16P>
    <Radar1-Deuta>true</Radar1-Deuta>
    <Radar1-SRR>false</Radar1-SRR>
    <Radar2-Deuta>true</Radar2-Deuta>
    <Radar2-SRR>false</Radar2-SRR>
    <Profibus>true</Profibus>
    <Profinet>true</Profinet>
  </HW-configuration>
  <STAC-Release></STAC-Release>
  <EVC-SW-Version></EVC-SW-Version>
  <Duration></Duration>
  <activated_Xtraces>0</activated_Xtraces>
  <SystemFailure>false</SystemFailure>
</Scenario>
```

Therefore I have written the following code:

```
@staticmethod
def parse_xml(xml_path):
    xml_path = os.path.abspath(xml_path)
    tree = etree.parse(xml_path)

def main():
    parse_xml(r"D:\z003e42d\2017\TIDAT\Scenario-XMLs\Test_wig_0002.xml")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

... and got the following Error Message:

```
  File "src\lxml\lxml.etree.pyx", line 3427, in lxml.etree.parse (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:81101)
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 1828, in lxml.etree._parseDocument (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:118056)
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 1848, in lxml.etree._parseMemoryDocument (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:118325)
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 1729, in lxml.etree._parseDoc (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:116883)
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 1063, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseUnicodeDoc (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:110870)
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 595, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:105093)
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 706, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:106801)
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 635, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:105655)
  File "<string>", line 1
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Start tag expected, '<' not found, line 1, column 1
```

But why do I get such a strange Error-Message isn't it possible to pass an absolute path to a xml to the parser? I did also try the following because I have read about StringIO in the documentation.

```
tree = etree.parse(StringIO(xml_path))
```

But that did not work too. For me the xml looks right or is something missing right there?

I hope you could help me.

Comment: The XML file in the question is well-formed. But the one that you actually try to parse is not well-formed.

Comment: But the xml I show you right here is the xml i try to parse

Comment: I have found out my error. Like shown here it works fine with the given xml. I have just put in tree = etree.parse(StringIO(xml_path)). Without StringIO it works fine.